# Subset Sum Requirements

Tags: complexity-theory

Consider the following problem.

> Given a set $S$ of integers, a function $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ and $k \in  \mathbb{Z}$, decide wether there is $X \subseteq S$ such that $f\left(\sum_{x\in X}x\right)=k$.

Is this still considered a [subset-sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum)?

For instance, given

$\qquad \displaystyle S=\{ −7, −3, −2, 5, 8\}$

and $k=0$, find a subset $X$ such that $f\left(\sum_{x\in X}x\right)=0$ for $f(y)=-3+y$. In this case, a solution is $X=\{ -3,-2,8 \}$.

Comment: Isn't $k=0$ without loss of generality?

Comment: @Jeff Seems so. For $f$ and $k \neq 0$, there is an equivalent $f'$ with $k' = 0$.

Comment: When exactly do you mean by "Is this still considered a subset-sum problem"?  Are you asking whether you can call an instance of such a problem (i.e. given an $f$) as 'a variant of subset sum'?

Answer (score 7):

It depends on the form of $f$. If $f(x) = x$, then it is identical to subset-sum. If $f(x) = 0$, then it is a trivial problem with an $O(1)$ solution: return $true$. You can possibly define $f$ in other ways to make the question more or less difficult, as well.

See below a mini-complexity zoo corresponding to different choices of $f$:

- for $f(x) = c$, the problem is $O(1)$ (*return true iff $c = 0$*).
- for $f(x) = 0$ for $x \geq 0$ and $f(x) = 1$ otherwise, the problem is $O(n)$ (*linear search for any number greater than 0*)
- for $f(x) = 0$ for $x \geq c$, $c > 0$, $f(x) = 1$ otherwise, the problem is no more than $O(n \log n$) (*sort the items in the set in descending order, and see if any prefix sums to a working solution*)
- for $f(x) = ax + b$, the problem is as hard as subset-sum (in an informal sense, and I don't provide a construction to demonstrate the reduction from subset-sum to this... if I'm wrong about this one, please let me know!)
- for $f(x) = 0$ if the Turing machine encoded by $x$'s binary representation halts when given the binary representation of $x$ as input (alternatively, when given the empty tape as input, and similar kinds of halting problems), and $f(x) = 1$ otherwise, the problem is undecidable (*a solution to the problem for this $f$ could solve the halting problem*)

Anybody see anything else fun?

Comment: 1) "the problem is equivalent to subset-sum" -- do you mean this literally or "as hard as"? 2) In the last bullet you should give $x$ as input to the TM; as it is, you solve *some* halting problem but not the canonical one.

Comment: 1) Yes, I mean "as hard as", in a sort of informal sense. Of course I don't provide a construction for that, but it seems to be right... of course, I have been surprised before, and this could be wrong. Editing to make this clear. 2) Right, I debated at first whether I should do that or not, but hearing you suggest that it's better that way is enough for me.

Comment: Does `as hard as' mean the problem is NP-Complete.  Would that make it a reduction of Subset Sum or 3-CNF SAT?  Is there a proof laying bare the reducibility of a subset with this special case of having an equation whose values are integers and whose solution is 0?

Comment: @Patrick87 your second bullet is on par with where my inquiry is leading me.  Can you expand on this portion to discuss its NP-Completeness in detail?

Comment: @Char Subset-sum is a special case of $f(x) = ax + b$ (let a = 1, b = 0). To see the other reduction, solve for $f(x) = x + b/a$ after dividing all set elements by a (problem is scale invariant). As others have pointed out, it's already well-known that the problem with $f(x) = x + c$ is "as hard as" the canonical subset-sum (that is, where $f(x) = x$).

Comment: @Char: Patrick claims that is is NP-hard (i.e. at *least* as hard as NP-complete problems) but does not provide a proof. As SUBSET-SUM is a special case of the problem with $f(x)=ax+b$, it is likely that he is correct.

Comment: @Raphael Kaveh claims the result is simple enough to not warrant a proof.

Answer (score 6):

You can get arbitrary difficult problems depending on your $f$.

Let $A$ be a language. Define $f$ as follows:
$$f(x)= \begin{cases} 0 & x\in A \\ 1 & o.w. \\\end{cases}$$

Consider set $S=\{x\}$. There is a non-empty subset $X\subseteq S$ s.t. $f(\Sigma_{x\in X} x) = 0$ iff $x \in A$.

Without putting a complexity requirement on $f$ you can get problems of arbitrary difficulty.

An interesting case is when $f$ is of restricted complexity, e.g. polynomial time computable. In that case we can use it to invert $f$, so the problems can be as difficult as inverting an arbitrary polynomial time function (and assuming that there are polynomial time computable psuedo-random number generators which are hard to invert in subexponential time, it means you cannot solve the problem): let $g$ be an arbitrary polynomial time computable function. Assume that we are given $y\in Range(g)$ and we want to find an $x$ s.t. $g(x)=y$. Define $f(x)=g(x)$. Let $S= \{0,1,2,4,8,\ldots, 2^m\}$ for suitable large $m$ (to make sure that a preimage of $y$ can be represented as sum of the numbers in the set). At each set we will remove a number $2^i$ from the set and check if there is still a subset $X$ s.t. $f(\Sigma_{x\in X} x)=y$. If the answer is yes, we know there is a solution that doesn't need that number, so we remove it from $S$ permanently. If the answer is no, we know that we need that number for all solutions. After $m$ steps we will have a set $S$ which is a solution and no subset of it is a solution, so we can return $x=\Sigma_{x \in S} x$ as our answer.

On the other hand, if $f$ is polynomial time computable, the problem will be in $\mathsf{NP}$.

In the special case that the function $f$ is linear, since $\Sigma$ commutes with linear functions, the problem is the same as solving the subset-sum over $f(S) = \{ f(x) \mid x \in S\}$. As long as the linear function is not constant the problem will be as hard as subset-sum, i.e. $\mathsf{NP\text{-}hard}$ (if you want to solve the subset-sum instance $(S,k)$, apply $f^{-1}$ to members of $S$ to obtain $S'$ and then use the modified version on $(S',k)$ to solve it).

(This trick will also work for more general case where the function $f$ is polynomial time computable and has an inverse that is also polynomial-time computable.)

Comment: if arbitrary, how do I determine if my function will produce an NP-hard complexity?  The linearity?  Can you source a proof of this? Also, what do you mean `on the other hand'?  Your restricted complexity example uses polynomial time computability as your restriction, and then you suggest `on the other hand' but continue talking about polynomial time computability?  Also, in your last paragraph I was confused by the comment `as long as the linear function is not constant', but isn't the subset sum problem constant in nature?  0, or 1?  Thanks for the thorough reply.

Comment: I have assumed in my answer that $f$ is a priory fixed function. If you want it to be part of the input, then you have to define how $f$ is given first. Let's say it is given as a finite string which is the code of a Turing machine computing it, then you cannot. You should ask a separate question if you want to know why complexity of a given Turing machine is not a decidable problem.

Comment: "Can you source a proof of this?" I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: "On the other hand" is still about polynomial time $f$, the difference is that it is giving an upper bound on the complexity of the problem.

Comment: If $f$ is a constant function, then the problem is trivial since independent of what $X$ you select, $f(\Sigma_{x \in X}x)$ will be the same. "isn't the subset sum problem constant in nature? 0, or 1?" again, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: By source a proof I meant can you give a reference, or source, for a proof stating that a subset sum using a linear function is NP-Hard.

Comment: @char, I essentially gave you the proof. I don't think you find reference for simple results like this.

Comment: f = $\frac{(N \mod x)}{(N-x)(1-x)}$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is still [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), but instead of finding a subset whose sum is $0$, you are required to have a sum that equals something else (in your example it 3, in general it is $f^{-1}(0)$, which might be a set of numbers if $f$ is [many to one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function)).

This doesn't change much the difficulty of the problem for bijective $f$, but otherwise depends on the number of preimages $f^{-1}(0)$ has. As stated already, if $f(y)=0$, the problem becomes trivial.

Comment: The issue here is you are looking for a number x=3 for f(x) to equal 0, but you do not know that is the value you require, and instead of solving the equation you use a subset sum to find the value by testing to see if the function returns 0.

Comment: You should edit the question to clarify this point. As said, everything depends on $f$. If you don't "know" it (but only has an black-box access to it, the answer is different (as demonstrated by @patrick87)

Comment: You know $f$, you do not know $x$.  Can you suggest a rewrite to the question.  I have the handicap of knowing what I meant and am finding it difficult to reword the question to clarify any further.  What is still unclear to those reading it?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're looking for. If you know $f$, (assuming it is simple), why can't you invert it to find its root (the value x that makes $f(x)=0$, and then solve the subset-sum with this value as target?

Comment: Because $f$ allowing any real number transforms any input to zero, but limiting the input to only integers, as the subset sum problem stipulates, produces only unique values of $x$.

Comment: Sorry?  What does "produces only unique values of $x$" mean?  Consider the _integer_ functions $f(x) = x\bmod 2$ and $f(x) = \min\{0, x^2 - 100\}$.

Comment: @RanG. Simple functions are not necessarily simple to invert.  See all of public-key cryptography!

Comment: @JeffE "simple" is vague on purpose. As for inverting a function - this depends if the function is fixed for the problem (then the time for inverting it is irrelevant), or is given as an input. The question was not well-defined for that point.

Comment: @RanG., it is not simple to invert even if the function is fixed, e.g. try inverting the multiplication function in polynomial time :)

Comment: @kaveh I think you misunderstood what I'm saying. I make a distinction between $f$ which is part of the input (and then the time it takes to convert it matters), and $f$ which is part of the problem definition, and then the time it takes to invert it is not part of the algorithm that solves the subset-sum  (i.e., existential solution).

Comment: @RanG., no, I understand what you are saying, what you are saying is not correct. Even if $f$ is fixed, it does not helps. Take a look at my answer, where I supposed that $f$ is fixed and is not part of the input.

Comment: @kaveh If $f$ is invertible and $f^{-1}(0)$ is finite ("simple"), then subset-sum-$f$ is at most $NP$. For other $f$'s I agree with you.

Comment: @RanG., yes, in case that $f$ is polynomial time invertable or $k$ is fixed (not part of input) and $f^{-1}(k)$ is finite (or more generally enumerable in polynomial time) then what you way is correct.